# Environment Path Variable Not working properly

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, bashrc

I've edited my .bashrc file because of errors like the one below keeps popping every time I open a terminal.

```
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

So far I've tried( in my .bashrc file):

1. `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin`
2. `exportPATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`
3. `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`
4. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`

still, I've to enter explicitly one of the above-said commands in the terminal every time I open a new one. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ls resides in `/bin`. But apparently you have messed up your PATH somehow; on a clean Ubuntu install PATH is set in `/etc/environment`. Can you please edit your question and show us what `echo $PATH` outputs.

Comment: The PATH should be set in your ~/.profile, not ~/.bashrc, though that's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson when I echo $path, this shows up  $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: That's very wrong. Please remove all tweaks of PATH you have made to start with.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That tweak was necessary for Hadoop installation which I was following.

Comment: In any case you did it wrong. If you want help to correct it, you need to show us exactly what you did.

Comment: I followed this link ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7h5KEyEF5tEYm1GX0QwWWFDWm8 ) for Hadoop installation.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Bash-Shell you should define the PATH Variables the following way in your **.bashrc**:

PATH="/bin:/usr/bin/: **and other paths**:$PATH"

**Print the Path env-varibale**

```
printenv PATH
```

So that we can see what happens.

Comment: /bin and /usr/bin are included in the default PATH. There shouldn't be any need to add them again.